# Bootstrap Carousel: Indicators not cycling

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to implement the carousel from Bootstrap.

Everything is working fine except the carousel indicators ('.carousel-indicators') are not cycling through with the slides.

[Here is a completely stripped down page](http://dev.magzalez.com/bootstrap-question.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
<meta name="description" content="">
<title>Test Home Page</title>
<link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/stockpr-test-store/esph2/files/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<style>
    li.active {
        color:red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Test</h1>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/960x500/fff/000" alt="Slide 1"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/960x500/fff/000" alt="Slide 2"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/960x500/fff/000" alt="Slide 3"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Carousel nav -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
    </div><!--//container-->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/stockpr-test-store/esph2/files/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel();
</script>
</body>
```

This is almost an exact duplicate of the example on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel. Any ideas as to why they wouldn't be sliding?

Comment: If you inspect the indicators while the carousel is sliding does the active class appear and disappear from the LI elements?

Comment: No indication of movement when inspecting the element. You can use http://dev.magzalez.com/bootstrap-questions.html to see a live version of the example.

Comment: I get a page not found for that url.

Comment: Ah, your link is wrong, it should be http://dev.magzalez.com/bootstrap-question.html (no 's' on question)

Comment: Yep, you're right. Edited link in question as well.

Comment: I don't think your bootstrap css file contains the code to deal with the carousel indicators. Is it an old css file? Try updating it to the latest version as the carousel indicators were only added on last weeks 2.3 Bootstrap release.

Comment: You may need to update your bootstrap javascript file too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update your Bootstrap css file and JavaScript file to the latest versions.

Comment: Looks like there was an update between when I started the project (last week) and now. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't get mine to work (no idea what was going on) but here's how I got it to look like it:

### HTML

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="myCarousel-target active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="myCarousel-target"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="myCarousel-target"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div data-slide-no="0" class="item carousel-item active"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/960x500/fff/000" alt="Slide 1"></div>
        <div data-slide-no="1" class="item carousel-item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/960x500/fff/000" alt="Slide 2"></div>
        <div data-slide-no="2" class="item carousel-item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/960x500/fff/000" alt="Slide 3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 2000});
        $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function() {
            var to_slide = $('.carousel-item.active').attr('data-slide-no');
            $('.myCarousel-target.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.carousel-indicators [data-slide-to=' + to_slide + ']').addClass('active');
        });
        $('.myCarousel-target').on('click', function() {
            $('#myCarousel').carousel(parseInt($(this).attr('data-slide-to')));
            $('.myCarousel-target.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know why my carousel was not working but manually adding the above did resolve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Here it is

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
          <!-- Carousel items -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div id="0" class="item active">
                <img src="image/snow1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>
                  <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="1" class="item">
                <img src="image/snow2.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4>
                  <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div> 
          <!-- Carousel nav -->

          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel();
  $('.carousel').on('slid', function() {
    var to_slide = $('.carousel-inner .item.active').attr('id');
    $('.carousel-indicators').children().removeClass('active');
    $('.carousel-indicators [data-slide-to=' + to_slide + ']').addClass('active');
  });
});
</script>
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: FonkyJu, this looks like a good workaround! and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it just with deleting bootstrap-carousel.js from /js folder!